Is posible install old version of adminjs
I'm searching an admin template for an application based on NodeJs+Express+Sequelize.
I find Adminjs that seem like very usefull for my purpose, but i read in documentation that is deprecate Js syntax for ESM syntax.see here
Now my issue is that all app and API is just written in JS and i can't adapt all code to ESM.

Is there a solution?
I can mix ESM and plainJS module?
Or is possible to install 6.x version of AminJs?
Is there an alternative that support sequelize on express?

Thanks for your help

Give it a try to combine plain JS into ESM
